# Cannot find reference 'messagebox' in 'tkinter.py'

Tags: python, tkinter

Module import error:
[image]

I`m tring to import the messagebox from tkinter module, I saw on the internet and it is the same. I dont know what is wrong with it. I did some researches on the internet but I still can't solve this :((
I have a file named tkinter, I'm using python 3.11 and I when I try to run the code the same error shows up

Comment: Do you have a file/folder named `tkinter`? What python version are you using? Also have you tried actually running your code. Does that give any errors?

Comment: I have a file named tkinter, I'm using python 3.11 and I when I try to run the code the same error shows up

Comment: If you have a file/folder named `tkinter`, python will try to import from it instead of the `tkinter` that comes with python. In general if you have a project with `tkinter` you should avoid naming files `tkinter.py` and folders `tkinter`.

Comment: IT WORKED TYSM <3333